# Dynamic web page scraping in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

How to scrape a dynamically uploaded web page in Python?
Is it possible in Python?

Like when using Beautifulsoup we can scrape only the static content of a web page.
But I want to scrape a dynamically uploaded web page.

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no. It depends on the site. If you could add more detail to your post, we might be able to give pointers.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I want to scrape data from http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings link for OVERALL PLAYER STANDINGS. Would you please guide me how to scrape in python..?

Comment: @ Oliver: Would like to get each player's details, if you click on Gary Ablett get some data.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic pages use **JavaScript** to change the content of page by pressing a button and ...
You can handle JavaScript with a python library called **selenium**, that way your 
web-driver will click a button and ... for you if you want to; so you will be able to scrape that page with beautiful soup.
**Note** that beautiful soup just can grab content that is **shown currently on page**.
This is what you will do every time:

1. Open the URL with selenium and your browser web-driver(you can search to download)
2. Find button, tabs or any thing that makes page dynamic and command a click with 
   selenium.
3. Grab pages source code with beautiful soap and scrape what information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) to do most things you would do in a browser.

> Stateful programmatic web browsing, after Andy Lester’s Perl module WWW::Mechanize.
>
> mechanize.Browser implements the urllib2.OpenerDirector interface. Browser objects have state, including navigation history, HTML form state, cookies, etc. The set of features and URL schemes handled by Browser objects is configurable. The library also provides an API that is mostly compatible with urllib2: your urllib2 program will likely still work if you replace “urllib2” with “mechanize” everywhere.
>
> Features include: ftp:, http: and file: URL schemes, browser history, hyperlink and HTML form support, HTTP cookies, HTTP-EQUIV and Refresh, Referer [sic] header, robots.txt, redirections, proxies, and Basic and Digest HTTP authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you go for `selenium`. All it does is it opens up a browser and does exactly what a real user would do. You can click buttons and do any thing a real person can do in a website. A simple google search will give you a lot of tutorials. I would explicitly add documentation link because who even reads them :p

Answer (score 0):

You can do this solely with BeautifulSoup and Requests library. What you will wanna do is reverse engineer the API call the website is making. This can be done by checking into the developer settings and going to network tab. Thank you, hope this helped !